# Can I sort list by second argument in Python?

Tags: python

I have an external .txt file that looks like this:

```
Year of birth (yyyy); id; First name; Second name;
...
Year of birth (yyyy); id; First name; Second name;
```

Can I make a new list that sorts all elements by `bbbb` part?

I tried doing it by splitting all elements then sorting it, but like that I lose other elements that are connected to that `id`.

Comment: maybe you can specif what the bbbb part is, it is not listed in your example.

Comment: please post a minimu example of sample of your input file, your code you have tried and your expected output. Absoloutley its possible to sort a list by any required ordering

Comment: Write a function to return the date part from a given string and pass it as the ‘key’ parameter to ‘sort’.

Comment: Is `bbbb` the `id`?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to approach this using builtin functions and modules, or third party libraries like `pandas` as mentioned in other answers.

Using simple builtin functions, you can create a sorted list from a file by passing the file object to the [**`sorted`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function:

```
with open(filename) as file_object:
    lines = sorted(file_object)
```

This works because `sorted` accepts any sequence or iterable object. File objects are iterable and yield a line at a time.

This will sort alphabetically starting from the first character of each line, then comparing the second, etc.

As you want to sort by the second string between the semicolons, you need to extract that string and sort by that instead. There are numerous ways to do this.

The `sorted` function takes a `key` argument. You should pass a function here which will be called for each line, and would return the criteria for comparing the line with other lines.

For example we can split the line into a list of separate strings:

```
>>> line = '1998;1234;Jim;Smith;'
>>> line.split(';')
['1998', '1234', 'Jim', 'Smith']
```

Then we want to compare the second value from the list (we count from `0`, so the second value is `[1]`):

```
>>> line.split(';')[1]
'1234'
```

Create a function which does this, and we can then pass it to `sorted` as the `key`:

```
def get_id(line):
    return line.split(';')[1]

with open(filename) as file_object:
    lines = sorted(file_object, key=get_id)
```

Probably though you want `lines` to be processed more so that for each line you have a list of values. Python has a builtin [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for handling delimited values (you're using semicolons):

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

with open(filename) as file_object:
    reader = csv.reader(file_object, delimiter=';')
    rows = sorted(reader, key=itemgetter(1))
```

In this case we can use [**`itemgetter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) instead of having to write `get_id`, as the `csv` module has already done all the splitting for us, and we just need a function which can get the second item in the row.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a possible answer.

Sample string of items in your text file:

```
sample = """1998; 1; Jim; Smith;
2001; 2; Andrea; Johnson;
1995; 3; Tom; Jones;"""
```

We'll create a multidimensional array (list of lists) by splitting our string, splitting the line and appending to our main array.

```
matrix = list()
for record in sample.split('\n'):
    line = [i.strip() for i in record.split(';') if len(i) > 0]
    matrix .append(line)
```

Our matrix:

```
[
['1998', '1', 'Jim', 'Smith'],
['2001', '2', 'Andrea', 'Johnson'],
['1995', '3', 'Tom', 'Jones']
]
```

To **sort**, you can use the built-in method for a list and implement a lambda function to pick which column you'd like to sort by.  Note: Since indexes in Python start at zero, you'll have to take that into consideration.  For the example, x[1] means the second item, or the `id` column:

**Sort 1**: Descending ID order

```
matrix.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Output 1:

```
[
['1995', '3', 'Tom', 'Jones'],
['2001', '2', 'Andrea', 'Johnson'],
['1998', '1', 'Jim', 'Smith']
]
```

**Sort 2**: Descending birth year order (youngest to oldest)

```
matrix.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=False)
```

Output 2:

```
[
['2001', '2', 'Andrea', 'Johnson'],
['1998', '1', 'Jim', 'Smith'],
['1995', '3', 'Tom', 'Jones']
]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
list1 = """1999;id2;mike;smith;1996;id3;steve;jones;1998;id1;john;smith"""
list2 = list1.split(';')


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
columns = ['year','id','first','last']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(list2,(-1,4)),columns=columns)
###### by='id' if you want to sort by id, or replace with('year','id','first','last') whatever you want to sort by.
df.sort_values(by='id',inplace=True)
list3 = df.values.tolist()
list3
output:
[['1998', 'id1', 'john', 'smith'],
 ['1999', 'id2', 'mike', 'smith'],
 ['1996', 'id3', 'steve', 'jones']]
```

Comment: Numpy and pandas are pretty heavy duty modules for such a simple question.

Comment: @PeterWood I do agree they are heavy packages but they are also one of the most commonly used. So people downvote cause I solved it using this method. This why stackoverflow is bs. Peter How would you solve it?

Comment: Like I said in my comment on the original question.

Comment: list1 is invalid syntax

Comment: @PeterWood thanks for the heads up I fixed it. I see you have many more years of experience than I. what would be a better solution.

Comment: I've posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59514095/1084416). Hope it helps.